# Smart Subscript

Tags: replacement, subscript

I have a question about subscript policy. For some reason I have some variables called `Subscript[q, 1]`, `Subscript[q, 2]`, `Subscript[q, 3]` and `Subscript[q, 4]`. I know that I could have called them in other ways, but even (not only) for them to be more human readable I decided to call them this way.
Now I have the expression

```
Series[Sin[q Subscript[q, 3]], {q, 0, 0}]
```

which is not evaluated as I want. To cricumvent this I wrote

```
Series[Sin[q q3], {q, 0, 0}]/.{q3->Subscript[q, 3]}
```

which works, but is not elegant. Is that an elegant way to make Mathematica understand that *in this case* the subscript is just the name of a variable?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Some use the ``"Notation`"`` package. Or perhaps `Subscript["q", 3]`? One particular problem is that the `q` is the same variable in both factors of `q Subscript[q, 3]`; the other is that `Subscript[q, 3]` is treated as a function of `q`, which you cannot avoid. Since you're willing to type `q3`, you could try something like `Format[q3] = Subscript["q", 3]`, especially if output formatting is the goal; see also `MakeBoxes[]`.

Comment: Both versions of your command result in the same result for me (`O[q]^1`).  Do you have an example where the results differ and you can say which you want?

Comment: Concerning subscripts, I added the same issue. I know use the "Notation" package. It runs event it is quite long to define all my variables like this.